# How to find the MAC addresses of an unsecure network, on Windows, using the easiest steps?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, mac-address

As I try to prove that an insecure network, even with MAC filtering feature, is a bad thing (link [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/657272/wifi-password-vs-macs-filtering-in-terms-of-speed-vs-security)) , I've tried to find out the easiest way to do so.

I'm trying to show that it's easy to enter such a network . I've already seen many links saying this, and that it's easy to do it.

Since Windows is still the most popular PC OS, I've tried to find answers about it. I know that linux is very popular for this task and that there is even a linux distro exactly for these type of security checks (called "backtrack" ), but I want to show that it is easy for everyone.

I also know that there are even tutorials for Windows (like [**this one**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPavZ6m5gG4)) but i couldn't find any that involves a working , free solution .

What I know is that proving this would take 2 steps:

1. find the MAC addresses of devices that are already connected to the insecure network.
2. spoof the MAC address of one of them.

for #2 i've find some easy apps (like etherChange for windows, and MacMan for Android).

However, for #1 I couldn't find an easy, free solution on Windows.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Am I even in the right direction? Maybe I could do packets sniffing after spoofing the MAC address of the access point itself? If so, what should I search for there, and which tool is the easiest for this task?

Comment: Most of the tools to do this were written on linux because of the portability.  Most of these tools work with cygwin for this reason.  Have you tried the tools that were already suggested.  Its a trivial task to setup a linux virtual machine.

Comment: i've tried something with "airmon-ng" on Linux but since i couldn't figure out why it doesn't have the needed executables I've stopped since that's too much to ask for what I'm looking for. for a home network, there is little chance that the neighbors would go this far. i want to prove that it's simpler even than that.

Comment: A better way to phrase this question is "why **isn't** there an easy way to do this in Windows?", because there isn't one.

Comment: @Moses no, since installing Linux isn't something that is considered as a mean to do something on windows. it's not on windows. it's on Linux. and by saying that there isn't an easy way to do this on windows, you actually mean that it's hard to overcome the Mac filtering, since most people still use Windows.